# django-registration adding additional fields in the registration form

Tags: django

I am interested in adding additional fields in the registration form, like
nickname and date of birth.

I am using django-registration 0.8, and I am planning to write my own custom form. I have looked at django-profiles and I think that the privacy control with that is not strong enough.

I plan to store these additional info in another database (mongodb) where I have direct access to them via a variable ( my_db). Which function should I overwrite in order to control where the data from the custom form will go to?

Answer (score 7):

The register view allows you to pass a custom form_class. From `registration.views`:

```
def register(request, success_url=None,
             form_class=RegistrationForm, profile_callback=None,
             template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
             extra_context=None):
```

Subclass the RegistrationForm and override the save method on that and put your custom stuff in there. Then override the view in your project's urlconf.

```
url(r'registration/', register, {"form_class": YourNewRegistrationForm}),
```

Comment: Not sure why he didn't accept this -- this is the right answer, worked for me.

Comment: I think you need to put the backend on newer versions of Django and django registration url(r'registration/', register, {'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend",form_class":YourNewRegistrationForm}),i